# How to call the servlet filter(having dependency of other object) in web.xml. Need xml Equivalent of given springboot filter configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I need to use a third party filter in my application.
I am using external jars(see import statements in code) for this filter. Added dependencies for the filter jar in pom.xml.
Now I want to call this filter, however not sure how can I do so with xml configuration. I have the correct springboot equivalent code to apply this filter.

(My project uses servlets+spring (but no spring boot) but I still tried adding below code by adding spring boot dependency but the filter does not work) Can anyone help me with the xml equivalent of below code?

````
package com.dd.demo;


import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import com.ext.auth.Access; //this is external jar class
import com.ext.auth.filter.AuthFilter; //this is external jar class 


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.dd.demo")
public class AuthConfig {

   @Bean
    public Access access() {
        Access access = new Access(new String[]{"path=C:/Users/config.properties"});
        return access;
    }
    @Bean(name = "authFilter")
    public Filter authFilter() throws ServletException {
        return new AuthFilter(true,access());
    }
   @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean authFilterRegistration() throws ServletException {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(authFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registration.setOrder(0);
        return registration;
    }


} ```
````

Comment: The Spring java-code filter registration can register Filter from "external" jars too.

Answer (score 1):

To inject spring bean as dependency we can use 'org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy' as a filter class in web.xml like below :

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
```

By using DelegatingFilterProxy, we're able to define our filter as a bean in the applicationContext.xml instead of adding the filter directly into web.xml.

```
<bean id="access" class="Access">  
        <property name=path value="C:/Users/config.properties"/>
</bean>
<bean id="authFilter" class="AuthFilter">  
        <constructor-arg ref="access"/>
</bean>
```